# Encoding / Encryption in IHttpHandler Urls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encryption, encoding, urlencode

I am using `IHttpHandler` to get data from a `database` for filtering purpose. But, I am facing a problem with some filter values which contain special characters like `"&"`,`"/"` etc.

> How can I pass those Filter values with Special Characters to Process Request?

**UPDATED**

```
 function filter_Click(element_clicked) {
 var colName = $(element_clicked).attr("data-id");
     $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: "../../Handlers/FilterValueHandler.ashx?ColumnName=" + colName + "&filter_text=" + $('#hndSelectedValue').val(),
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (response) {}
});
}
```

In the above code `$('#hndSelectedValue').val()` is a hidden element whose value is using for filter which I have to send to the server for filtering. This value in `JSON format`.

> How can I pass those Filter values with Special Characters to Process Request?

Comment: From where do you want to pass such filter values?
Could you make a specific example?

Comment: @tyger I am using an 'ajax call from a javascript function' to call that IHttpHandler. Arguments for this ajax call have special charecters like "&","/", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use standard JavaScript function `encodeURIComponent()` to encode you value to pass it as GET parameter in URL

```js
//skipped
url: "../../Handlers/FilterValueHandler.ashx?ColumnName=" + colName + "&filter_text=" + encodeURIComponent($('#hndSelectedValue').val()),
```

later in your server code use `System.Uri.UnescapeDataString()` method to decode it back.

```cs
var decodedValue = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(Request.QueryString["filter_text"]);
```

In addition see [URL Encode a string in jQuery for an AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544564/url-encode-a-string-in-jquery-for-an-ajax-request)
and [How do I decode HTML that was encoded in JS using encodeURIComponent()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022832/how-do-i-decode-html-that-was-encoded-in-js-using-encodeuricomponent)

Comment: Ok @tyger I wil take your suggestion, Thank Yu

Comment: I have some other issue with same filter because of the Url Length(Requested URI is too LONG). Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Hm, how long is your filter then? It seems that it have to be send to server side as a POST parameter not GET. See [jQuery.ajax reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).  
There is problem with formatting in comments, see my next answer. And it's better to make another question regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED**

**In javascript

```
function EncryptText(toEcode) {
    var Key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("AMINHAKEYTEM32NYTES1234567891234");
    var IV = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("7061737323313233");
    var encryptedText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(toEcode), Key, {keySize: 128 / 8, iv: IV, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });
    return encryptedText;
}
```

** In C# Code

```
 public static String AES_decrypt(string encrypted)
    {
        encrypted = encrypted.Replace(' ', '+');// This line resolved my Issue
        var Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("AMINHAKEYTEM32NYTES1234567891234");
        var IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("7061737323313233");
        byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
        AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        aes.KeySize = 256;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aes.Key = Key;
        aes.IV = IV;
        ICryptoTransform crypto = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        byte[] secret = crypto.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
        crypto.Dispose();
        return System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(secret);
    }
```

Comment: Wow, wow, slow down, you **mustn't use a cryptography to encode and decode values with special symbols** - it's to expensive in meaning of computer resources on both sides: client's and server's. It's bad way. 

Look at my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax request to pass long value to server as POST request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../../Handlers/FilterValueHandler.ashx?ColumnName=" + colName,
    data: {"filter_text":$('#hndSelectedValue').val()},
    success: function (response) {}
});
```

#### UPDATE:

On the server side get it from request with `Request.Form["filter_text"]`

Comment: I am getting a 'Value cannot be null' error message in Handler ProcessRequest() method where we are taking the filter-test from the request, CODE:-                                                         var filter_text = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(context.Request.QueryString["filter_text"]);

Comment: @JKANNAN In that case you have to use `context.Request.Form["filter_text"]` to get your value.

Comment: Try to use Developer tool in your browser something like Network and look at what is being sent in fact to server.