# Creating a mutable SVG with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I would like to create a resizable SVG using JavaScript. If you run the code, you'll notice the "svgTriangle[0].innerHTML = "<polygon points='";" line does not get appended inside the SVG tag. If someone could help me figure out why this is not getting appended, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

```js
var svgTriangle = document.getElementsByClassName("svg-triangle");
var bgTrianglePoints;

function updateOnResize() {
  bgTrianglePoints = [
    [0, 0],
    [window.innerWidth * 0.76, 0],
    [window.innerWidth * .16, window.innerHeight * 1.2],
    [0, window.innerHeight * 1.2]
  ];

  svgTriangle[0].innerHTML = "<polygon points='";
  for (var i = 0; i < bgTrianglePoints.length; i++) {
    svgTriangle[0].innerHTML += bgTrianglePoints[i][0] + "," + bgTrianglePoints[i][1] + " ";
  }
  svgTriangle[0].innerHTML += "'/>";
}

window.onresize = function() {
  updateOnResize();
}

updateOnResize();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 85vh;
}

.svg-triangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg-triangle"></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: SVG will resize by itself. Here's one I made earlier https://github.com/QuentinUK/quentinuk.github.com/blob/master/spiral.html

Comment: Please read about [createElementNS()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) Also read about [How to save / add all special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39694148/how-to-save-add-all-special-characters-like-etc) in javascript Also use a viewBox, don't use window.innerWidth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, why the first line does not appear in the HTML, it is probably because it makes the HTML invalid. You could instead use the `document.createElementNS` method as follows:

```js
const polygon = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");
```

to create the `polygon` element in the SVG namespace.

Then, you can create the string for the points attribute:

```js
let points = "";

for (var i = 0; i < bgTrianglePoints.length; i++) {
    points += bgTrianglePoints[i][0] + "," + bgTrianglePoints[i][1] + " ";
  }
```

and finally set the attribute on the element:

```js
polygon.setAttribute("points", points);
```

Now, you can use `svgTriangle.appendChild(polygon)` to add the polygon to the HTML.

Another possibility is to use the `points` property on the polygon element, which is an [SVGPointList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPointList) and use [`appendItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPointList/appendItem) on it in a loop to add the points, but that is quite much code and not really necessary. Also, [SVGPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPoint) is already deprecated...

Comment: Beautiful, thanks